# How to select this element with Scrapy XPATH?

Tags: xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

Only requirement: it needs to refer to the `thread-navigation` class, because that page has many other pagination elements

```
<section id="thread-navigation" class="group">
<div class="float-left">
<div class="pagination talign-mleft">
<span class="pages">Pages (6):</span>
<span class="pagination_current">1</span>
<a href="I want this text?page=2" class="pagination_page">2</a>

<a href=""I want this text?page=3" class="pagination_page">3</a>
<a href=""I want this text?page=4" class="pagination_page">4</a>
<a href=""I want this text?page=5" class="pagination_page">5</a>
<a href=""I want this text?page=6" class="pagination_last">6</a>
<a href=""I want this text?page=2" class="pagination_next">Next &raquo;</a> //<--- this one
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

I was trying something like this:
`r.xpath('//*[@class="thread-navigation" and contains (., "Next")]').get()`
But it always returns `None`

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you have quoting issue: `href=""` Is it a typo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not referring to an `@class` attribute, but rather to an `@id` attribute with the value `thread-navigation`. So try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
r.xpath('//a[ancestor::*/@id="thread-navigation" and contains (text(), "Next")]/@href').get()
```

Its result is

> I want this text?page=2

Comment: Thank you, my bad for mixing id and class... 
In the meantime, I found this awesome xpath generator for chrome and it does a very good job
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-generator/dphfifdfpfabhbkghlmnkkdghbmocfeb/related

Answer (score 0):

This xpath:

```
'//section[@id="thread-navigation"]//a/@href'
```